# How to make Thunderbird highlight related messages, a la apple mail

Tags: thunderbird

Is there any way to have Thunderbird highlight related email messages (that is, belonging to the same conversation) just like Apple Mail does?

Below is an example screenshot of an Apple mailbox:  one message (September 13) is selected  and one related message (May 23) is automatically highlighted

[image]

Comment: I wish Thunderbird did this too.  Great feature!

Answer (score 0):

Just found a link for adding a 'Conversation View' to Thunderbird: [MozillaZine - Message Grouping](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Message_Grouping).  The most relevant link on that page is [Conversation View add-on ?(for gmail)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gmail-conversation-view/?src=ss).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Conversation view groups the messages. I don't want the grouping, I want the highlighting. I've included a sample inbox image to my question to clarify

Comment: My bad, I would check Thunderbird add-ons, I'm guessing you've done that though.

Comment: Do any of these approximate what you want. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/search/?q=highlight+by+sender&appver=&platform=

Answer (score 0):

I also miss this feature. The closest addon I've found is this one 
[Gather the senders](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/thunderbird/addon/gather-the-senders/). Currently it can only select messages by author. So, I left a comment with same feature request there.

Comment: Hello, viktorp welcome to superuser, if you could when answering a question add detail with the source link as often the links can change and then the users have no information to work from.  Thankyou